# How to find hidden properties/methods in Javascript objects?

Tags: javascript, python, introspection, hidden

I would like to automatically determine all of the properties (including the
hidden ones) in a given Javascript object, via a generalization of this
function:

```
function keys(obj) {
    var ll = [];
    for(var pp in obj) {
        ll.push(pp);
    }
    return ll;
}
```

This works for user defined objects but fails for many builtins:

```
repl> keys({"a":10,"b":2});  // ["a","b"]
repl> keys(Math) // returns nothing!
```

Basically, I'd like to write equivalents of Python's dir() and help(), which are really useful in exploring new objects.

My understanding is that only the builtin objects have hidden properties (user code [evidently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636453/is-it-possible-to-create-a-hidden-property-in-javascript) can't set the "enumerable" property till HTML5), so one possibility is to simply hardcode the properties of Math, String, etc. into a dir() equivalent (using the lists such as those [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref)). But is there a better way?

**EDIT:** Ok, the best answer I've seen so far is on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257993/how-to-display-all-methods-in-a-javascript-object/2313745#2313745). You can't easily do this with your own JS code, but the next best thing is to use console.dir in Chrome's Developer Tools (Chrome -> View -> Developer -> Developer Tools). Run console.dir(Math) and click the triangular drill down to list all methods. That's good enough for most interactive/discovery work (you don't really need to do this at runtime).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[ECMAScript 5th ed.](http://www.ecmascript.org/docs.php) defines `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` that returns an array of all properties of the passed in object, including the ones that are non-enumerable. Only Chrome has implemented this so far.

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames({a: 10, b: 2});
```

gives `["b", "a"]` (in no particular order)

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Math);
```

gives `["LN10", "PI", "E", "LOG10E", "SQRT2", "LOG2E", "SQRT1_2", "LN2", "cos", "pow", "log", "tan", "sqrt", "ceil", "asin", "abs", "max", "exp", "atan2", "random", "round", "floor", "acos", "atan", "min", "sin"]`

Comment: Aha. So this is how Chrome is doing it -- I thought they had hardcoded it.

Answer (score 4):

`Object.getOwnPropertyNames` won't return "the hidden ones".
`Object.getOwnPropertyNames` returns the names of non-inherited properties.

Answer (score 3):

This is explained in a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257993/how-to-display-all-methods-in-a-javascript-object/2258232#2258232).  Basically, the spec explicitly requires (using `DontEnum`) that these objects aren't enumerable.

Comment: Sure. I think that the console.dir answer in that thread was what I was looking for, so thanks for pointing me to it.

Answer (score 0):

this works in firebug to find object methods.

> > > Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Math);