# Is there a way to hide Object.prototype's property?

Tags: javascript, prototype-chain

If I add a property to Object.prototype like
Object.prototype.sth = "something";

then, is there a way to hide the property for a specified object?
I tried like this:

```
function Foo() {
// sth...
}
Foo.prototype = null;
var bar = new Foo();
```

however,
bar still have access to the property sth;

---

`bar.__proto__ = null` or `Foo.prototype.__proto__ = null` works

Comment: Why ? What are you trying to do ?

Comment: It's not possible, but you can take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2636719/2183827

Comment: I'm just trying to understand the concept of prototype chain…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the way to do this is:

```
  function Foo() {
         this.sth = null
// or this.sth = undefined;
    }

    var bar = new Foo();
```

- `Foo.prototype = null;`: the `bar.__proto__` will point directly to
  `Object.prototype`.
- Without `Foo.prototype = null;`: the `bar.__proto__` will point to `Foo.prototype`, and `Foo.prototype.__proto__` points to `Object.prototype`

Another way:

```
function Foo() {
// sth...
}
Foo.prototype.sth = undefined;
//or Foo.prototype.sth = null;
var bar = new Foo();
```

Comment: It's just add a property to the object to preven Javascript to travel the prototype chain

Comment: @YOnder: i think it's one of the ways. You may use Foo.prototype.sth undefined;

Comment: Anyways, you have to override it by using its own properties or a nearer prototype properties.

Comment: Got it. I can assign the null value for the bar.__proto__

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you override `Foo.prototype` with `null`, the Foo's attributes will be deleted.

```
Foo.prototype.sth = 1;
bar = new Foo(); # Creates {sth:1}
Foo.prototype = null;
bar = new Foo(); # Creates {}
```

Take a look to the [documentation page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype) :

> all objects inherit methods and properties from Object.prototype Object.prototype, although they may be overridden (except an Object with a null prototype, i.e. Object.create(null)).