# How to expose only a function and not the variables from a class function?

Tags: javascript, class, variables

Suppose I have this code:

```
function GraphFactory() {

  this.nodeNames = [];
  this.pinnedNodes = [];


  this.initPinnedNodes = function(nodes) {
    if (nodes) {
      this.pinnedNodes = nodes;
    } else {
      this.pinnedNodes = [];
    }
  }
  this.checkIfPinned = function(node) {
    if (this.pinnedNodes.indexOf(node) > -1) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
  this.addToPinnedNodes = function(name) {
    this.pinnedNodes.push(name);
    return true;
  }
  this.removeFromPinnedNodes = function(name) {
    this.pinnedNodes.splice(this.pinnedNodes.indexOf(name), 1);
    return true;
  }
}

let graphFactory = new GraphFactory();
```

Right now i can access both the function

```
graphFactory.checkIfPinned(label);
```

but also directly the variable

```
graphFactory.pinnedNodes
```

How would I set things up so only the functions, but not the variables could get accessed?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636453/is-it-possible-to-create-a-hidden-property-in-javascript is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use variables instead of properties on the object.

```
let nodeNames = [];
```

They'll be closed over by your dynamically assigned instance methods.

Or see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22156326/private-properties-in-javascript-es6-classes) for the modern approach.

Comment: Use `let` when declaring the variable.

Answer (score 0):

With the current construct, you can use a closure per object, practically a local variable in your constructor function:

```
function GraphFactory() {
  var nodeNames = [];
  var pinnedNodes = [];

  this.initPinnedNodes = function(nodes) {
    if (nodes) {
      pinnedNodes = nodes;
    } else {
      pinnedNodes = [];
    }
  }
  this.checkIfPinned = function(node) {
    if (pinnedNodes.indexOf(node) > -1) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
  this.addToPinnedNodes = function(name) {
    pinnedNodes.push(name);
    return true;
  }
  this.removeFromPinnedNodes = function(name) {
    pinnedNodes.splice(this.pinnedNodes.indexOf(name), 1);
    return true;
  }
}

let graphFactory = new GraphFactory();
```

However such variables will not be accessible to methods you add later, from outside. For example that `nodeNames` exists in vain this way.